Dual Monitors - One transition between 2 monitors catches mouse
Here are the details of my issue
I have a three monitor setup. Between the transition of monitor 2 and 3 on GPU 1, the transition always sticks. This transition is highlighted in the red box in the image below. (This is not occurring outside of this highlighted area nor am I having an issue figuring out where my monitors are with my cursor) In fact, it requires a certain mouse velocity in order to break the barrier between the two monitors. At the same time, the transition between monitor 1 and 2 is effortless. This only occurring between one set of my monitors leads me to believe the issue is not associated with Windows Sticky Corners. Instead, I think it may have something to do with GPU 1. At the same time, I have no idea why the GPU would impose a transition barrier between two of the monitors without providing a config for the feature.
I have also not seen anything in the NVIDIA Control Panel that would provide relief from this annoying issue.
I've been dealing with this since I built this computer back in 2020. It doesn't matter what mouse I use.
Ease cursor movement between displays is checked for all monitors.
Your help is appreciated.
Here is my setup
Hardware
GPU 1: Nvidia GT 1030
GPU 2: Nvidia RTX 3080 OC
Mouse: Logitech G502
Config
GPU 1: monitor 2 and 3 connected
GPU 2: monitor 3 connected
OS
Windows 11 Pro 23H2
Monitor 3 is primary display


The only thing I can think of off-hand is you may have inadvertently left a tiny gap between Monitor 1 and 2 (kinda looks like there's a 1 pixel gap in your screenshot), thus it would only jump between them if the mouse was travelling fast enough to skip over the pixel gap.
To see if this is the issue, leave the top Monitor 2 where it is, then carefully readjust Monitor 2 to snap up against Monitor 1.
I've had lots of issue with multi-monitors and passing the mouse from one to another, for example if the resolution of a Monitor is changed, where it snaps to also changes!  This can break things really easily.  Or cases where it's easy to pass the mouse from Monitor A to B, but not from B to A (gets stuck a lot).
Usually wiggling around the Monitor snap points solves these mystery issues.
Hope it works for you!

Thanks for the answer Raven. It seemed obvious at first since I've tried re-adjusting those monitor locations many times. I guess I didn't get them lined up as well as I thought. I overlapped them when placing the monitors and that snapped them in the right spot. Also, you were right, if you look closely enough at my image, you can see the pixel wide gap. Thanks again.

Happy to hear the solution worked for you!  Microsoft's multi-monitor configuration tool is pretty low quality, I've had many problems with it.
